# MSBuild can't build application with %PATH% env variable

Tags: docker, command-line, msbuild

I have a dockerfile who build a .net application :

```
FROM myPersonalRegistry/msbuild:14.0
SHELL ["powershell"]

#Copy .net application source code
COPY . 'C:\\build\\'
WORKDIR 'C:\\build\\'
RUN ["nuget", "restore", "-ConfigFile", "NuGet.Config"]

# Build with full Path
RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe", "Application.sln"]

# Try to build using PATH env variable
RUN setx PATH '%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\'
RUN ["MSBuild.exe", "Application.sln"]
```

The first msbuild works well, but not the second :

> container xxx encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"MSBuild.exe Application.sln","WorkingDirectory":"C:\build","CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}

I already try to pass the full path : `RUN ["MSBuild.exe", "C:\\build\\Application.sln"]` without success.

Please, What I'm doing wrong ? I would like to understand

Comment: 1. Have you checked if the setX command works, I mean if the msbuild path have been added into PATH(check the PC's environment variables). 2. If the msbuild path have been added to Path variable, then what's the result you run cmd.exe, and type 'msbuild'?  Can cmd recognize the msbuild command?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thanks for your comment, yes `setx` works well, and `MSBuild` or `MSBuild.exe` direct command works too.